# Django view not rendering correctly after view execution via template

Tags: django

I have this template: folder.html. I have a button on it that calls a view called calculate_folder. This view makes some calculations and then renders back to folder.html.

The problem is that when it renders, the view calculations are made, but the link in the browser is still the same (localhost:8000/calculate_folder/pk).
Here is some sample code to showcase the issue:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def calculate_folder(request, pk):
    folder = get_object_or_404(Folder, id=pk)
    folder.status = 'P'
    folder.save()
    context = {
        'folder': Folder.objects.get(id=pk)
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/folder.html', context)
```

Here is the urls.py content:

```
path('calculate_folder/<pk>', views.calculate_folder, name='calculate_folder'),
```

And here is the template itself:

```
<div class="inner"><a href="/calculate_folder/{{folder.pk}}"><input type="submit" style="width: 10em;" class="profile-edit-btn btn-info mb-2" name="btnAddMore" value="Calculate"/></a></div>
```

I want to click on the button, go to the url, execute the view, but go back to the initial page.

Answer (score 0):

Return redirect in your calculate_folder view.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def calculate_folder(request, pk):
    # Your function
    # instead of return render(request, 'dashboard/folder.html', context)
    folder = Folder.objects.get(id=pk)
    return redirect(folder.get_absolute_url())
```

`redirect` will call Folder's `get_absolute_url()` method, [see here for more details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).

You should put your button in a form, with csrf token, and restrict method on the view to POST.

Comment: I will try to add the redirect but I have a question, why put the button in a form?

Comment: I am getting this error:

`AttributeError at /calculate_folder/1

'Folder' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'`

Comment: Put it in form to send a POST request. You should never use GET when the view is modifying your database.

Comment: You get that error because you haven't defined get_absolute_url() on your model class. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

Comment: Now it gives me this: `Exception Type:  NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:  

Reverse for 'views.details' not found. 'views.details' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`